# Compiler misses invalid constructor call and calls non-existant (or private) default constructor

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a constructor of a class that inherits from several other base classes:

```
Derived::Derived() :    MyRpc< Derived, DERIVED_RPC_CLASS_ID, true  > ( Derived::sServerName ),
                    MyEventSource<Derived>( *this ),
                    Smasher<Derived>( *this )

{ 
}
```

The default constructor of Smasher is being called.  What is also strange, is that if I make the default constructor of Smash private or if I outright delete it, the compiler is still generating a public default constructor and calling it.

Here is how I have smasher defined:

```
class SmasherBase
{
    SmasherBase()=delete;
    SmasherBase( const char *name)
    {}
    .
    .
};

template< typename ... >  class Smasher : public SmasherBase
{
    Smasher()=delete;
};

template< typename LocalServerRPC_T >
class Smasher<LocalServerRPC_T> : public SmasherBase
{
public:
    Smasher()=delete;
    Smasher( LocalServerRPC_T &localServer, const char *name ) : SmasherBase( name ),
                                                                    mLocalServer( localServer )
    {
        ....
    }

    ~Smasher()
    {
    }

    typedef Smasher<LocalServerRPC_T>   Smasher_t;

protected:
    LocalServerRPC_T    &mLocalServer;
};
```

I would expect the compiler to complain that I am not calling an existing  constructor as in:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'Smasher<Derived>::Smasher(EksoCAT&)'
```

But it happily compiles the above code and then creates a default constructor over and above my objections.  It also creates and calls a default constructor for the base class as well.

I have even tried making the default constructor private, hoping that it would at least realize that it shouldn't create a compiler generated default constructor in its place and perhaps complain that the constructor is private.

No such luck.  The code is happily generated and when I run, and I can step into the phantom default constructor.

I am using the GNU 4.8.3 C++ compiler.  I have also cleaned, rebuilt, searched for old versions of these files to make sure they weren't being used, etc, etc to no avail.

Thank you all for any help and ideas.

Comment: If you can reduce the code to a [mcve], that will be very useful

Comment: But where is the code that attempts to invoke the deleted default constructor? The code you provided so far does not even attempt to use the default constructor. For which reason the fact that it is deleted does not cause any errors. You claim that "The default constructor of Smasher is being called". Where is that call? Your first code quote uses `Smasher<Derived>( *this )`, which is definitely *not* the default constructor.

Comment: @AnT  You identified my problem.  I am not even calling it.  If I step into the Derived's constructor, and then step into Smasher's constructor, it steps into the default constructor (compiler generated for Smasher).

Comment: @RSahu Thanks, will do.  That idea escaped me...one sec

Comment: @Kevin Stallard: What do you mean by "it steps into the default constructor"? Your default constructor is deleted. How can it step into it? What exactly do you see?

Comment: @AnT  Exactly.  The compiler is still generating it.  The calls stack reports that I am in Smasher<Devived>::Smasher().

Comment: @Kevin Stallard: But your original question clearly states that the constructor is invoked from `Derived`. Your `Derived` invokes `Smasher<Derived>( *this )`. This is not default constructor invocation. This constructor might be still compiler-generated, but it is not *default* one, since it has a parameter. What made you think that the compiler-generated constructor that you stepped into was the *default* one?

Comment: @AnT  Again, you are seeing my problem.  1.  I am not calling a default constructor.  2.  I am deleting the default constructor 3. The constructor I am calling doesn't even exist   4.  The debugger is showing that I am in the default constructor.

Comment: @Kevin Stallard: At this point I don't believe you correctly interpreting what you are seeing. The compiler stepped into *some* compiler-generated constructor. You for some reason assumed that it is the *default* one. But it actually isn't. I'm trying to figure out what made you think that it was the *default* one. But you are providing no information.

Comment: 5.  The compiler should pick up the fact that the constructor I am attempting to call is non-existant.

Comment: @Kevin Stallard: Agian, where in the code are you attempting to call the non-existant constructor??? Post the code with the call. Your first quote is not it.

Comment: @AnT  The evidence I have is that the debugger is showing Smasher<Derived>::Smasher() when I step into it.

Comment: @AnT  I am not trying to call the default constructor.  I have stepped into Derived's Constructor as it is in my original post.  Really, this is all I have done.  I am working up a simple example to see if I can reproduce it....

Comment: @Kevin Stallard; This could simply be some misleading output from the debugger. Your first code quote clearly makes a call with a single argument. Which means that it will call some constructor of `Smasher` that *has parameters*. It cannot possibly call the default constructor.

Comment: Derived::Derived() :    MyRpc< Derived, DERIVED_RPC_CLASS_ID, true  > ( Derived::sServerName ),
                    MyEventSource<Derived>( *this ),
                    Smasher<Derived>( *this )

{ 
}

Comment: @AnT Take a look at Derived's constructor as I posted it....this is what I am stepping into.

Comment: I see it. And again, it makes a call with a single argument. Which means that it will call some constructor of `Smasher` that has parameters. It cannot possibly call the default constructor. If you see `Smasher<Derived>::Smasher()` in  the debugger, it could simply be a misleading output from the debugger. I.e. it calls a conversion constructor `Smasher<Derived>::Smasher(const Derived &)` or something like that, but the debugger says something misleading at UI level.

Comment: @AnT  I know, that is what I thought as well.  Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: @AnT  And to add insult to injury, the compiler isn't complaining that the constructor with a single parameter doesn't exist.   So, not only is the compiler not complaining, the code calls a default constructor.

Comment: @Kevin Stallard: If `Derived` inverits from `Smashed`, then it calls one of the inherited *copy constructors* (`Smashed::Smashed(const Smashed&)`), slicing the right-hand side from `Derived` to `Smashed`. Copy constructors are compiler-generated as well, and you never deleted them. Delete `Smashed`'s copy constructor and I'm sure you will get the compiler error in response.

Comment: @AnT  Okay, that makes more sense.  So you are suggesting that calling Smash( *this )  (since this == Derived and Derived inherits from Smashed) that the compiler is creating a copy constructor.  That would explain it...thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My psychic debugging skills tell me that your class `Derived` inherits from `Smasher<Derived>`. In that case, your call to `Smasher<Derived>(*this)` is in fact calling `Smasher`'s *copy constructor* which you haven't deleted or defined yourself, so the compiler will happily generate one for you. The debugger is almost certainly simply not showing you the exact constructor being called.

Comment: Sorry Mark that I don't have a higher reputation here.  I would like to do something nice for both you and AnT....